# Why is the error string comparison not working on Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, string, compare, equals

```
if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("300 OK")){
    Log.d(result, "in 300 OK BUT UNKNOWN : "+ result);
    MyGPS.location_info = "Unknown";
}else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("400 ERROR"))
    Log.d(result, "400 ERROR : "+ result);
else Log.d(result, "else : "+ result);
```

Above is a simple test that `result` is `"300 OK"`.

The problem is that when I expect `"300 OK"`...

```
 07-29 14:06:56.126: VERBOSE/doing background(5807): 300 OK
```

...it actually goes to the `else` case...

```
07-29 14:07:00.494: DEBUG/(5807): else : 300 OK
```

Why does it do this? It should show:

```
in 300 OK but unknown
```

Comment: you expect the result to be equal to 300 ok, but have you logged the result before the if to see if it's correct?

Comment: are you sure your result is "300 OK", and not " 300 OK". Try trimming it first

Comment: I suggest you log *exactly* what's in the string - its length, and the Unicode value of each character. This kind of thing can easily be caused by unprintable characters etc. Just logging the length would be a good start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result string seems to be longer/different from the string literal you compare it to. Maybe [contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) is a better choice of method (compared to equalsIgnoreCase). Use it together with [toLowerCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa989676%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to achieve case-insensitivity if you need to.

Comment: How about :  
if (results.contains ("300 OK") && !result.contains("location"))   
?

Comment: we have 300 OK|location
300 OK
400 ERROR
so can't use contains

Comment: Both Maggies comments might be useful.

Comment: that's a lot help the problem is have space , btw thk for advice :)

Answer (score 0):

```
result.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("300 OK")
```